# Adding an Image to my UIButton subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subview

I have a `UIButton` that is added on my super view as a subview, It is just a big block, how do I add an image to my button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(890, 345 , 100, 100);
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

[self.collectionView.superview addSubview:button];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeContentOffset:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: `[button addSubview:yourImageView]`?

Comment: you have lots of answers now. If one of them solved your problem, please accept it. Else comment the answers and ask for more information/tell your problem or incompability with it ;)

Comment: RTFM! This question should be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, here is how:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal && UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add `image in UIButton` by following two ways.

1) With help of setting `Background Image`.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(890, 345 , 100, 100);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.collectionView.superview addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeContentOffset:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

2) Or you can add `UIImageView` as `subview`.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(890, 345 , 100, 100);
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [button setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [button addSubview:imgView];    
    [self.collectionView.superview addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeContentOffset:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
    -setBackgroundImage:forState:

Answer (score 0):

you may looking for something like this, if you want to have an "image as button" and not only a default button with an image inside

```
BOOL ipad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];;
CGRect frame;
//universal app 
if (ipad)
{
    btn.frame = frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
}
else
{
    btn.frame = frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
}
btn.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonAsImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal && UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. 
First one is you can add an imageview to your superview and set imageview's image whatever you want. Then, at the same position add your button with size of imageview and set button color to clearColor. But you need to add imageView first otherwise your button will be under the image.

Second one is default image to button, use setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal or setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:).

`- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`